# Why can't I declare bitfields as automatic variables?

Tags: c, syntax, stack, bit-fields

I want to declare a bitfield with the size specified using the a colon (I can't remember what the syntax is called). I want to write this:

```
void myFunction() 
{   
  unsigned int thing : 12;
  ...
}
```

But GCC says it's a syntax error (it thinks I'm trying to write a nested function). I have no problem doing this though:

```
struct thingStruct
{
  unsigned int thing : 4;
};
```

and then putting one such struct on the stack

```
void myFunction() 
{   
  struct thingStruct thing;
  ...
}
```

This leads me to believe that it's being prevented by syntax, not semantic issues.

So why won't the first example work? What am I missing?

Comment: Your title is technically wrong since a function local variable that is a struct is an automatic variable.  You can even put `auto` in front of it (as opposed to `extern` or `static`).

Comment: Can you suggest a better title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, bitfields must be declared inside a `struct` (or `union`, but that's not really useful). Why? Here are two reasons.

- Mainly, it's to make the compiler writer's job easier. Bitfields tend to require more machine instructions to extract the bits from the bytes. Only fields can be bitfields, and not variables or other objects, so the compiler writer doesn't have to worry about them if there is no `.` or `->` operator involved.
- But, you say, sometimes the language designers make the compiler writer's job harder in order to make the programmer's life easier. Well, there is not a lot of demand from programmers for bitfields outside `struct`s. The reason is that programmers pretty much only bother with bitfields when they're going to cram several small integers inside a single data structure. Otherwise, they'd use a plain integral type.

Other languages have integer range types, e.g., you can specify that a variable ranges from 17 to 42. There isn't much call for this in C because C never requires that an implementation check for overflow. So C programmers just choose a type that's capable of representing the desired range; it's their job to check bounds anyway.

C89 (i.e., the version of the C language that you can find just about everywhere) offers a limited selection of types that have *at least n bits*. There's `unsigned char` for 8 bits, `unsigned short` for 16 bits and `unsigned long` for 32 bits (plus signed variants). C99 offers a wider selection of types called `uint_least8_t`, `uint_least16_t`, `uint_least32_t` and `uint_least64_t`. These types are guaranteed to be the smallest types with at least that many value bits. An implementation can provide types for other number of bits, such as `uint_least12_t`, but most don't. These types are defined in `<stdint.h>`, which is available on many C89 implementations even though it's not required by the standard.

Comment: C99 also adds `unsigned long long` with at least 64 bits.  In most cases, these (the plain types) are all you need.

Answer (score 7):

The first example won't work because you can only declare bitfields inside structs. This is syntax, not semantics, as you said, but there it is. If you want a bitfield, use a struct.

Comment: So the answer is "just because"? Fair enough! Wikipedia's K&R example (wikipedia:Bitfield) shows single bits per field. I can understand them having to be in a struct in that use case. But I'm using the numbers primarily to assert that the sizeof the type is big enough.

Comment: @Joe: There are minimum defined sizes for the types - for the unsigned types, it is 8 value bits for `unsigned char`, 16 value bits for `unsigned short` and `unsigned int`, 32 value bits for `unsigned long` and 64 value bits for `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 4):

Why would you want to do such a thing? A bit field of 12 would on all common architectures be padded to at least 16 or 32 bits.

If you want to ensure the width of an integer variable use the types in `inttypes.h`, e.g `int16_t` or `int32_t`.

Comment: Very good point. I will take your advice in this case. But the question still stands in abstract. And the numbers given in the text were arbitrary.

Comment: @Joe: "But the question still stands in abstract".  Answer: there's no need to do such a thing!

Comment: @Joe: the only reasonable numbers on modern architectures are 8, 16, 32 and 64 for such a thing.

Comment: @Joe: alignment requirements make what you want to do difficult for a compiler to support.  In practice your fields would be aligned to the nearest native word size, so it really doesn't buy you anything over using `int` or `long` or `short`.  Bitfields are useful within the context of a struct (such as mapping the bits in a processor status word), not so much outside of it.  Like Jens says, if you need words of specific sizes, use the types in `inttypes.h`.

Comment: @Jens: there are still some oddball architectures out there where the word size isn't a multiple of the byte size (e.g., 8-bit bytes, 36-bit words), so I could see wanting something like a 9-bit field.

Comment: I don't want to copy-paste a comment, but see my comment on JSBangs' answer for the reason behind asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

Bitfields provide a consistent syntax to access certain implementation-dependent functionality.  The most common purpose of that functionality is to place certain data items into bits in a certain way, *relative to each other*.  If two items (bit-fields or not) are declared as consecutive items in a struct, they are guaranteed to be stored consecutively.  No such guarantee exists with individual variables, regardless of storage class or scope.  If a struct contains:

```
struct foo {
  unsigned bar: 1;
  unsigned boz: 1;
};
```

it is guaranteed that bar and boz will be stored consecutively (most likely in the same storage location, though I don't think that's actually guaranteed).  By contrast, 'bar' and 'boz' were single-bit automatic variables, there's no telling where they would be stored, so there'd be little benefit to having them as bitfields.  If they did share space with some other variable, it would be hard to make sure that different functions reading and writing different bits in the same byte didn't interfere with each other.

Note that some embedded-systems compilers do expose a genuine 'bit' type, which are packed eight to a byte.  Such compilers generally have an area of memory which is allocated for storing nothing but bit variables, and the processors for which they generate code have atomic instructions to test, set, and clear individual bits.  Since the memory locations holding the bits are only accessed using such instructions, there's no danger of conflicts.

Comment: Thanks, that's a new and interesting perspective.

Comment: 'Consecutively' doesn't help much, if it's about bit fields possibly being stored inside a single octet. Or does it? Not too sure...